# Can I display user stories, tasks, and bugs using Azure DevOps Sprint Boards?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-boards, sprint

In Azure DevOps, I am setting up my team's 2-week sprints. I have the setting enabled: Bugs are managed with tasks. This is so that our user stories and bugs are at the same level and display in our product backlog.

Image of bug settings:

[image: Image of bug settings]

The problem, is that some of our bugs are simple enough, they don't require a task to be created against it. However, the sprint boards ONLY show tasks per person. Is there a way to show all tasks, user stories, AND bugs assigned per person per sprint??

Image of sprint - only tasks showing grouped by person:

[image: Image of sprint - only tasks showing grouped by person]

Answer (score 0):

[Grouping by team members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/task-board?view=azure-devops#group-by-team-members) is only **one** way of showing work items on the Taskboard.

You can switch to [grouping by Backlog items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/task-board?view=azure-devops#show-progress-on-items). This should give you a crisp view of all Work items scheduled for the sprint along with the progress of each.

[image: Group by backlog items]

So the Taskboard would then look like:

[image: Taskboard grouped by Backlog items]

You can additionally use the filters available to filter by work item types, states, assigned to etc..

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I am looking for a view that still groups these all by person. (without having to filter down each time). So ideally, I would see people on the left side, and all user stories, tasks, and bugs in the kanban board

Comment: @Dbevington Oh, so you want to be able to [show all work item types per person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLzC.png) and not just "tasks". Please check: [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi @bhargavi Annadevara , I did try that previously - the problem with that is now I don't see user stories as well. It always seems to be one or the other